# nfcd process taking 33% of cpu - what is that and why?

Tags: cpu, macos

Since a few days there is process called nfcd taking up 175% (33% of all cpu) of cpu an my MBP 13 with 10.15.7. It's even running when all apps are closed and after reboot of the Mac.

For some reason the process doesn't show up in the activity monitor but only in Menu Meters. I am able to kill the process with `sudo killall nfcd` but nevertheless, I'd like to know what is going on.

Comment: On my (Catalina) MacBook Pro the "user" of that process is something called "_applepay" So I would hazard a guess that it is an ApplePay daemon...

Comment: Hi, i have the exact same issue. Did you resolve it? how? @SteveChambers

Comment: @Kar19    cant't really tell... A lots of strange behaviour went away after stopping to use Time Machine via WiFi with a Time Capsule, but I can't swear that this was the problem.